# Manually adding IndexOutOfBounds Exception

Tags: java, arrays, exception

I'm trying to manually throw an index out of bounds exception for an array.
I know that to throw a regular exception, I can do something like:

```
if(x>array.length){
throw new Exception("Bad choice!");
}
```

But how can I do the index out of bounds exception?

Thanks

Comment: um,... perhaps `throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("for index, " + x)`? I'm guessing that it would have been quicker for you to have first tried this than post your question on SO.

Comment: Who downvoted my post (its deleted now) and why was it downvoted?

Comment: @fireshadow: it was a terrible answer, one that did not answer the question at all. The correct answer is in my comment above and sort of in testSubject below -- though he should pass the index into the exception parameter.

Comment: that if condition should be `x>=array.length || x<0`

Comment: @fireshadow - I downvoted because it was inefficient and unnecessary - why not just throw the ioobe? Not to mention that yours would actually throw an aioobe.

Comment: @Hovercraft Full Of Eels The question was kind of ambiguous to me... I'm sorry. :(

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("Index " + x + " is out of bounds!");
```

The [API](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/IndexOutOfBoundsException.html) is a very good resource. Checking it before posting a question could save you the time of doing so.

Answer (score 2):

You can do:

```
throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
```

Comment: `java.lang.*` is imported implicitly for all files

Comment: Couldn't remember for sure. Been a while since I've handled `java.lang.*` exceptions. Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("Index out of bound");

Why is this not working?

Comment: @Jeremy: how was it a problem of import?